# Mapping existing memory to Matlab mxArray without waste of memory

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers, memory, mex

I'm mex-ing a file for Matlab where I handle huge matrices (more than 20.000x20.000 double precision). I would like, after my computations are done, to map the resulting matrix treated as Eigen matrix to an mxArray without memory copying and allocating other space on memory.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd myfunction(const Eigen::MatrixXd &W)
{
    return W*2;
}

void mexFunction( int nOutputArgs, mxArray *outputArgs[], int nInputArgs, const mxArray * inputArgs[])
{   
    int M = mxGetM(inputArgs[0]);
    int N = mxGetN(inputArgs[0]);

    // Create the input matrix W as Eigen Matrix mapping the input matrix
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> W( mxGetPr(inputArgs[0]) ,M,N);

    // Allocate space for the output matrix G
    Eigen::MatrixXd G = myfunction(W);

    double *Gdata = G.data();
    outputArgs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M,N,mxREAL);
    memcpy(mxGetPr(outputArgs[0]), Gdata, sizeof(double)*M*N);

    return;
}
```

I'm asking if it is not possible to just align the pointer to `plhs[0]` to the pointer of matrix G ( which is obtained in Eigen as `G.data()` ) or do I need to do `memcpy`.

Comment: Check `mxSetPr`, it might do the trick: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetpr.html

Comment: I believe the pointer you pass to `mxSetPr` should be allocated using MATLAB's memory management functions (so, `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`). When Eigen allocates space for `G` it probably uses the standard C `malloc` or some other method. You might have to find out how to change the way it allocates memory, or resort to `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work (untested, no matlab ready):

```
outputArgs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0,0,mxREAL);
mxSetM(outputArgs[0], M);
mxSetN(outputArgs[0], N);
mxSetPr(outputArgs[0], Gdata);
```

Creating an empty matrix to start with prevents matlab from allocating a bunch of memory you don't actually need.

Though this might work, beware:

You will have to make sure that the `Eigen::MatrixXd` does not delete this memory block upon its own deletion once the `mexFunction` returns, which might well be whats going to  happen. Which would bring you back to `memcpy` again.